# Raphael network diagram

Tags: mysql, raphael

Does anyone know if Raphael the graphic library can produce network diagram that can interact (receive information and push changes back to the database) with a database through mysql?

Example:

http://cacoo.com/

But not can turn network represented by the graphics into data that can go into javascript, php and mysql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raphael draws. It does not talk to the server, and most certainly does not interact with SQL. Use another library for Ajax (jQuery comes to mind), and a serverside language for SQL, while using Raphael to put it all to screen.

Comment: Yes. That is what I mean. I am using php to interacts with MySQL. But I need to visualize my php output. When the user submit the modified network diagram, php will accept it and modify the Mysql.

But CAN RAPHAEL produce COMPLEX and INTERACTIVE(drag and drop) NETWORK DIAGRAM?

Comment: @William Sham: Yes, it can - it has all the necessary tools. But it's "not easy" - you'd have to implement it yourself.

Comment: @Amadan - yes I saw that. But i need those links to be edible, those boxes to contain info (essentially represents an object)

Comment: @thirtydot - What would be an easy option? When you say implement it do you mean I have to customize the code? I am just trying to figure out a direction/library to go

Comment: @William: Yes, there's code to be written. Raphael just makes a rather nice interface to SVG. You would make a group, put a rectangle in it, put a couple of lines of text in it, maybe an icon, then translate the group around. There, object. But I doubt you'd be able to make them edible - you'd have to warn your users to bring their own snacks.

Comment: @William Sham: I'd probably use Raphael myself. I don't know what the "easy option" is in this case. By "implement it" I mean you have to write JavaScript using Raphael's functions to do whatever you need..

Comment: @William: If you meant editable - they're changeable, programmatically, but there is no equivalent to `input` in SVG world, so either you would have to implement it yourself (handling keypresses, animating the cursor, updating the text, taking care of scrolling... very painful), or you would have a XHTML overlay `form` to handle the editing stuff (recommended and easy to do).

Comment: @Amadan - let me see if I understand your second options correctly. Say I have two square drawn, each contain a text field. I can name them abc[], such that I can accept it back in php as $_POST['abc'] when they submit the changed graphic. By edible, I don't mean free drawing. But maybe create process boxes for the network diagram, links them together or change the links, all these components are provided as tools to them. Do-able?

Comment: @thirtydot - thank you. Essentially, I need functionalities like http://cacoo.com/
But also can accept data

Comment: @William: As I said, there are no text fields in SVG. There is only text element, and it is not editable by users (only modifiable by JavaScript). Thus, you would make a XHTML `form` in the document outside the SVG canvas, as a dialog (easier) or as a sneaky overlay just on top of the rectangle (harder), which would then submit to your server, which would respond in some way, which would then make your code instruct Raphael to change the drawing in some way. Yes, doable.